# Matter node behavior in Matter protocol

Tags: mqtt, hardware, wireless, data-transfer, matter

What is the difference between MQTT and Matter protocol? Can I send Matter message between two different networks if Matter devices using link-local address?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Matter messages only work within the Matter fabric. That fabric could span several networks. As the Matter specification describes in 2.3.2 such a setup requires border routers.